# Losing flash values after location.reload()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form with `remote: true`. When the form is submitted, I want to respond with a `js` which renders the error messages if the record was invalid, but when it's saved, I want to reload the page, so I'm using `location.reload()` for that. However, I am assigning a value to `flash[:notice]` if the record was saved, but I lose it after `location.reload()` is executed. Is there any way I can mantain my flash messages after a `location.reload()`. If not, what are my alternatives? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose it because you're reloading the page.

Why do you need to reload? If it's to show the new record you can just have a create.js.erb file that appends or prepends the new record.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't. One of alternatives:

Instead of location.reload() you can redirect back with some additional URL parameters.

For example:

In controller:

```
# it's the same like location.reload() but adding 'status=success' extra parameter to url 
...
render js: "window.location = updateQueryStringParameter('#{request.referer}', 'status', 'success');"
...
```

JQuery:

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?|&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}
```

Then you can add filter to set flash message depending on status parameter:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  before_filter :check_status
  ...
  def check_status
    if params[:status]
      if params[:status] == 'sucess'
        flash[:notice] = "Success !!! Congratulations !!!"
      else
        ...
      end
      redirect_to url_for(params.except(:status)) # take away status parameter from url (if you wish)
    end
  end
```

Maybe a better way is to filter status parameter in middleware or in routes constraints instead of controller.